# Php sockets don't work properly (CentOS 7)

Tags: php, sockets, centos, centos7

```
<?php
function go(){
    $starttime = round(microtime(true),2);
    echo "GO() ... <br />\r\n";

    echo "socket_create ...";
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

    if($socket < 0){
        echo "Error: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error())."<br />\r\n";
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "OK <br />\r\n";
    }


    echo "socket_bind ...";
    $bind = socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', 889);//привязываем его к указанным ip и порту
    if($bind < 0){
        echo "Error: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error())."<br />\r\n";
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "OK <br />\r\n";
    }

    socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);//разрешаем использовать один порт для нескольких соединений

    echo "Listening socket... ";
    $listen = socket_listen($socket, 5);//слушаем сокет

    if($listen < 0){
        echo "Error: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error())."<br />\r\n";
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "OK <br />\r\n";
    }

    while(true){ //Бесконечный цикл ожидания подключений
        echo "Waiting... ";
        $accept = @socket_accept($socket); //Зависаем пока не получим ответа
        if($accept === false){
            echo "Error: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error())."<br />\r\n";
            usleep(100);
        } else {
            echo "OK <br />\r\n";
            echo "Client \"".$accept."\" has connected<br />\r\n";
            file_put_contents("res.txt", "OK ");
        }

        $msg = "Hello, Client!";
        echo "Send to client \"".$msg."\"... ";
        socket_write($accept, $msg);
        echo "OK <br />\r\n";

        if( ( round(microtime(true),2) - $starttime) > 100) {
            echo "time = ".(round(microtime(true),2) - $starttime);
            echo "return <br />\r\n";
            return $socket;
        }


    }


}

error_reporting(E_ALL); //Выводим все ошибки и предупреждения
set_time_limit(0);      //Время выполнения скрипта не ограничено
ob_implicit_flush();    //Включаем вывод без буферизации

$socket = go();         //Функция с бесконечным циклом, возвращает $socket по запросу выполненному по прошествии 100 секнуд.

echo "go() ended<br />\r\n";

if (isset($socket)){
    echo "Closing connection... ";
    @socket_shutdown($socket);
    socket_close($socket);
    echo "OK <br />\r\n";
}
?>
```

When the page with this code is opened it just starts infinitely loading

Port 889/tcp is opened

Machine has php 7.2 from remi repository with such plugins: php php-mysql php-gd php-ldap php-odbc php-pear php-xml php-xmlrpc php-mbstring php-snmp php-soap curl curl-devel php-mcrypt php-pecl-ap

What can be the reason of such problem? When connected nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that browser can't run sockets(You actually can do this, but you won't see what program returns), php sockets have to be run via console(Example: php filename.php). WAN ip(Global ip) should be used in socket_bind function.